# Do Angular Directive Factory Functions Get Invoked as Constructors of Functions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In Angular, when registering a directive to a module, does the directive factory function get invoked using new or just with simple function call?

eg.

```
var MyDirective = function() {
    return {
       link: function() { ... }
    };
}

module('myMod', []).directive('myDirective', MyDirective);
```

Does MyDirective get called internally as:

```
... = MyDirective();
```

or as

```
... = new MyDirective();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Angular Guide on providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#special-purpose-objects) states:

> Earlier we mentioned that we also have special purpose objects that
>   are (...) are Controller, **Directive**, Filter and Animation.
>
> The instructions for the injector to create these special objects
>   (with the exception of the Controller objects) **use the Factory recipe
>   behind the scenes.**

This fact be clearly seen in `compile.js` [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L767). And because we know that factory recipe in Angular simply invokes the function (with its dependencies, via `$injector.invoke(fn)`) so the correct answer to your question is `... = MyDirective();`

Answer (score 1):

It is invoked using an `$injector`, i.e. `$injector.invoke(MyDirective)`, so that dependencies can be resolved and injected. Internally, `$injector.invoke` call `MyDirective()`, *without* the `new`, and pass in the dependencies as arguments.